# Change namespace of WCF project without affecting clients

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces

We have created and deployed a WCF service which is being consumed by various third parties.

However we now want to change the namespace of the classes in that particular project. Is there anyway to do this without the third parties having to make any changes their end?

Example:

```
namespace Test.Service 
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface MyService 
    { 
         [OperationContract]
         List<People> GetPeople();
    }

    public class MyService : IMyService 
    {
         public List<People> GetPeople() 
         {
            // Logic here
         }
    }
}

namespace Test.Service.DTO 
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Person { }
}
```

to

```
namespace Something.Different
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface MyService 
    { 
         [OperationContract]
         List<People> GetPeople();
    }

    public class MyService : IMyService 
    {
         public List<People> GetPeople() 
         {
            // Logic here
         }
    }
}

namespace Something.Different.DTO 
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Person { }
}
```

It actually appears to be a problem mainly with the namespaces for the DTOs that are generated in the WDSL.

They are changing to

```
http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Something.Different.DTO
```

from

```
http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.Service.DTO
```

Which appears to be causing the results from the calls (which do not error) to not de-serialize so the List ends up being empty.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem as long that internally to the service you make all the refactorings, provided that :

- You only share WSDL with third parties
- Said another way : you did not provide third parties with a shared library holding the interfaces and `[DataContract]` classes

Regards